# Slim PHP bad redirection, get /public for any URI called

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, slim, server-configuration

I'm trying to install a [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) based webapp on a plesk server. The app is working fine in my WAMP server, but doesn't work in the web server. It must be a miss configuration of the server but I'm not able to find out which problem it could be.

In my app, I print `$this->app->request->getRootUri();` to access the called URI and I get : `/public` for any URI.

My `/httpdocs/.htaccess` looks like that :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/index.php    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/index.php/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

My `/httpdocs/public/.htaccess` looks like that :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea of what I could do in order to make my app work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the virtual path, slim use the pathInfo of the `env` variable, or script_name if slim is not installed in a sub folder. It should always be pathInfo.

So it is working fine on windows, but it is not working on linux if we don't put the project in a subfolder...